# java button pressed for 3 seconds

Tags: java, button, swt

I created a button and I want these:

When the user clicks the button, it stays pressed like 3 seconds. After 3 seconds the button should be again look pressable. So the user cannot click the button again without waiting 3 secs.
I tried these:

```
{
    button3 = new Button(c20, SWT.PUSH | SWT.CENTER);
    button3.setText("QUERY");
    button3.setBounds(205, 131, 62, 40);
    button3.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent event) {
            try {
                start_query();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        setPressedIcon();///??
        public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent event) {
        }
    });
}
```

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried using a countdown timer, and disabling the button while it's active? It should be fairly straightforward to disable the button when you press it, and start the timer, then re-enable it when the timer finishes. To make the timer, you can either just use an integer counter, or tap into the system clock using the Timer class.

Comment: for easiness, can i use 'for loops' for waiting?

Comment: @hassasin The swing timer is a better option than using for loops. It was designed for things like this.

Comment: @hassasin for-loops will kill your CPU and make your app unresponsive. Use appropriate Swing timer for this purpose. You should never perform long-running operations on the EDT (Event Dispatching Thread)

Comment: This is the exact same question you asked before. Don't do that. Improve your previous question or ask for clarification of the answers if you are not pleased with them.

Comment: @hassasin That's no reason to start a new question. Retag the old question and maybe ask for moderator attention to remove the "wrong" answers.

Comment: ok next time I will do it like that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May this help you

```
btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            btn.setEnabled(false);
            doSomething() ;
            btn.setEnabled(true);
        }
    });
```

Comment: That has an implied flaw in it that unless you have the button on it's own thread, the application will hang for 3 seconds, making everything, not just the button, unresponsive. Better to use a Timer and give it a separate condition, outside the event listener.

Comment: why did i get "The method addActionListener(new ActionListener(){}) is undefined for the type Button" error?

Comment: initially you mentioned as swing. swing contains action listener. you can update this in your selection listener

Comment: can you tell how i can use Timer, in below answer he/she used timer bu I got the "The constructor Timer(int, new SelectionListener(){}) is undefined" error? what can be the reason?

Comment: The reason is that you're not understanding how the basics of Java works. In this case, look up a tutorial on constructors and class definitions.

Comment: @hassasin were you able to resolve it. if not, let me know I will give u the answer in SWT

Comment: ok i couldnt solve it in SWG still dont know how to use actionlistener or timer, thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to spawn a new thread when the button is clicked.

```
 button3.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {
    public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent event) {
        try {
            Thread t = new Thread(){
              int count = 0;
              setPressedIcon();
              while(count < 4){
                 try{
                  Thread.sleep(1000);
                  count++;
                 }
              }
              setUnpressedIcon();
            }
            t.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    setPressedIcon();///??
    public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent event) {
    }
});
```

If you do it in the same thread as your UI, everything will be halted during the 3 seconds.

Comment: why did i get this error, 
setPressedIcon();(this method requires a body instead of a semicolon)?

Comment: Updating Swing components should not happen from that thread, but from the EDT. And any reason why you use the `while` loop to sleep for some seconds instead of just using `Tread.sleep` with the desired time.

Comment: It can still happen from the EDT if you use a handler. There was no reason, other than to make it explicit that we're counting seconds.

Answer (score 1):

```
btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
   btn.setEnabled(false);
   Timer timer = new Timer( 3000, new ActionListener(){
     @Override
     public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ){
       btn.setEnabled( true );
     }
   }
   timer.setRepeats( false );
   timer.start();
 }
});
```

I took the answer from @vels4j and added the `javax.swing.Timer` to it

Comment: what do these @Override mean?=) sorry

Comment: It means it overrides a method of the super class, or implements a method from the interface. That is really basic Java knowledge. [First hit in Google](http://stackoverflow.com/q/94361/1076463)

Comment: also I got this: The constructor Timer(int, new SelectionListener(){}) is undefined

Comment: @hassasin If those kind of error messages are a problem you should really start with a basic Java tutorial

Comment: I really should. I looked up everywhere I can not find the answer for it, why I am getting this error!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a PUSH `Button`, use a TOGGLE button. This way you can keep it pressed for as long as you require.

```java
final boolean buttonPressed[] = new boolean[] { false };
final Button button = new Button(comp, SWT.TOGGLE);
button.setText("Test");
button.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
        if (buttonPressed[0]) {
            button.setSelection(true);              
            return;
        }

        buttonPressed[0] = true;
        Display.getDefault().timerExec(3000, new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                button.setSelection(false);
                buttonPressed[0] = false;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling it, putting the thread to sleep for three seconds, then enable it again:

```
private void setPressedIcon(){
 try {
  button3.setEnabled(false);
  Thread.sleep(3000);
 } catch(InterruptedException e) {
 } finally {
   //reenable the button in all cases
   button3.setEnabled(true);
}
```